# How to force NASM to encode [1 + rax*2] as disp32 + index*2 instead of disp8 + base + index?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, micro-optimization, machine-code

To efficiently do [`x = x*10 + 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845914/sum-1-11-111-n-terms-in-x86-assembly), it's probably optimal to use

```
lea   eax, [rax + rax*4]   ; x*=5
lea   eax, [1 + rax*2]     ; x = x*2 + 1
```

[3-component LEA has higher latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466) on modern Intel CPUs, e.g. 3 cycles vs. 1 on Sandybridge-family, so **`disp32 + index*2` is faster than `disp8 + base + index*1` on SnB-family**, i.e. most of the mainstream x86 CPUs we care about optimizing for.  (This mostly only applies to LEA, *not* loads/stores, because LEA runs on ALU execution units, not the AGUs in most modern x86 CPUs.)  AMD CPUs have slower LEA with 3 components or `scale > 1` (http://agner.org/optimize/)

But NASM and YASM will optimize for code-size by using `[1 + rax + rax*1]` for the 2nd LEA, which only needs a disp8 instead of a disp32.  (Addressing modes always have a base register or a disp32).

i.e. they always split `reg*2` into `base+index`, because that's never worse for code-size.

I can force using a disp32 with `lea eax, [dword 1 + rax*2]`, but that doesn't stop NASM or YASM from splitting the addressing mode.  The NASM manual doesn't seem to document a way to use [the `strict` keyword](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.7) on the scale factor, and `[1 + strict rax*2]` doesn't assemble.  **Is there a way to use `strict` or some other syntax to force the desired encoding of an addressing mode**?

---

`nasm -O0` to disable optimizations doesn't work.  Apparently that only controls multi-pass branch-displacement optimization, not *all* optimizations NASM makes.  Of course you don't want to do that in the first place for a whole source file, even if it did work.  I still get

```
8d 84 00 01 00 00 00    lea    eax,[rax+rax*1+0x1]
```

---

The only workaround I can think of is to encode it manually with `db`.  This is quite inconvenient.  For the record, the manual-encoding is:

```
db 0x8d, 0x04, 0x45  ; opcode, modrm, SIB  for lea eax, [disp32 + rax*2]
dd 1                 ; disp32
```

The scale factor is encoded in the high 2 bits of the SIB byte.  I assembled `lea  eax, [dword 1 + rax*4]` to get the machine code for the right registers, because NASM's optimization only works for `*2`.  The SIB was `0x85`, and decrementing that 2-bit field at the top of the byte reduced the scale factor from 4 to 2.

---

But the question is: **how to write it in a nicely readable way that makes it easy to change registers, and get NASM to encode the addressing mode for you?**  (I suppose a giant macro could do this with text processing and manual `db` encoding, but that's not really the answer I'm looking for.  I don't actually need this for anything right now, I mostly want to know if NASM or YASM has syntax to force this.)

Other optimizations I'm aware of, like `mov rax, 1` assembling to 5-byte `mov eax,1` are pure wins on all CPUs unless you want longer instructions to get padding without NOPs, [and can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly) with `mov rax, strict dword 1` to get the 7-byte sign-extended encoding, or `strict qword` for 10-byte imm64.

---

gas doesn't do this or most other optimizations (only sizes of immediates and branch displacements):  `lea  1(,%rax,2), %eax` assembles to
`8d 04 45 01 00 00 00    lea    eax,[rax*2+0x1]`, and same for the `.intel_syntax noprefix` version.

Answers for MASM or other assemblers would also be interesting, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`NOSPLIT`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3):

> Similarly, NASM will split `[eax*2]` into `[eax+eax]` because that allows the offset field to be absent and space to be saved; in fact, it will also split `[eax*2+offset]` into `[eax+eax+offset]`.
>   **You can combat this behaviour by the use of the `NOSPLIT` keyword**: `[nosplit eax*2]` will force `[eax*2+0]` to be generated literally.
>   `[nosplit eax*1]` also has the same effect. In another way, a split EA form `[0, eax*2]` can be used, too. However, `NOSPLIT` in `[nosplit eax+eax]` will be ignored because user's intention here is considered as `[eax+eax]`.

```
lea eax, [NOSPLIT 1+rax*2]
lea eax, [1+rax*2]

00000000  8D044501000000    lea eax,[rax*2+0x1]
00000007  8D440001          lea eax,[rax+rax+0x1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I remembered seeing syntax for this mentioned somewhere.  I missed it when searching today because I assumed it would involve `strict`.  (And I didn't search super hard because I wanted to write up the performance part on SO :P)

Comment: You are welcome @Peter. Nasm doc is missing a keyword glossary IMO, I had to look at the source code. I was looking at what the other assembler do: TASM doesn't optimize, YASM has `NOSPLIT`, MASM 5 or older shouldn't optimize, new MASM I don't know (Not sure if I can find it w/o Visual Studio and make it work on Debian).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, a glossary would be useful as well as the existing *index*, where you have to know what you're looking for.  In hindsight, it would have made sense to look at the "effective address" section of the manual.

Comment: @MargaretBloom €ASM allows to switch off the optimization with keyword operand [SCALE=VERBATIM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/index.htm#SCALEeq).